# При создание foregn key в firebird выходит ошибка violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "PK_ROLES1" on table "roles"

Tags: база-данных, firebird

Я пытаюсь создать `foreign key` в таблице `user_roles`.В ней есть `user_id` и `roles_id`. Я создал `foreign key` для `user_id`. А для `roles_id` не получается создать.

Работаю в ibexpert.

```
alter table "users_roles"
add constraint FK_USERS_ROLES_2
foreign key (ROLE_ID)
references "roles"(ID)
on delete CASCADE
on update CASCADE
using index FK_USERS_ROLES_2
```

Выходит ошибка:

> violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "PK_ROLES1" on table "roles".Буду
> рад любой помощи.